# jqgrid inline editing with validation in grid using edit rules

Tags: jquery, validation, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid inline editing with validation in grid using edit rules for adding and updating values to the DB.

The problem is alert for validation fail comes after the values are submitted to the server

```
    colModel: [
     {name: 'Country', 
     index: 'Country', 
  editable: true, 
  edittype: 'text',
  sortable: false, 
     align: 'left', 
    search: false,
validation: { required: true }}
    ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `validation` property for items from `colModel`. You should use correct name of the property [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules):

```js
editrules: { required: true }
```

Moreover you can remove unneeded properties `edittype: 'text'` and `align: 'left'` (see default values in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options)). Because the value of `index` property is the same as the value of `name` you can remove it too.

Comment: @user1983094: Your error could exist in the part of your code which you not posted here. `editrules: { required: true }` means only that empty values will be not allowed for `Country` column during editing.

Comment: Editrules displays the validation message but it allows submitting the values to the server even if the validation fails

Comment: @user1983094: It's wrong. If you do have fond bug in jqGrid you should post full test case which reproduce the problem. Now we just spend our time.

Answer (score 2):

In **JqGrid**

Whenever we are trying to create or update a record in jqGrid it will raise error if there is any?

Two ways we can do it

1) **server side call** -

It will hit the server and return the responses to the grid through successfun() or errorfunction(), jqGrid can handle this automatically.

2) **Client Side Validation** -

It is used to validate the user input before submitting the value(s) to the server by using **editrules** option

**editrules**

This option add additional properties to the editable element and should be used in colModel.

syntax:

**{name:'price', ..., editrules:{required:true}, editable:true }**

**Customfunction :**

We can use our own custom function for that specific column By using **custom:true** Property